# Prove That $f(n+f(n))=n$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

if $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ is a function such that $f(1)=1$ and $$f(n)=n-f(f(n-1))\,\,\: \forall n \ge 2$$ Prove That $$f(n+f(n))=n$$

Comment: BULGARIA NMO 2010 http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=383979

Answer (score 1):

Prove by induction that the $k-1 + f(k-1) < n \le k+ f(k)$ contains one or two elements with image $k$.